# How to do a general search

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a simple browser using PyQt5 (By following a tutorial). It's mostly working except for one tiny problem -

```
def navigate_to_url(self): 
    q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())
    print(type(q)) 
    if q.scheme() == "":
        q.setScheme("http")
    self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q)
```

Whenever I type something in the address bar it searches it up but it adds a 'http://'. But if I want to search something like 'cats' I want it to work like a normal browser i.e. bring me links that are associated with cats.

Normal Pic:
[image: Normal Pic]

However because 'https://' is added it gives me a NAME_NOT_RESERVED error.

Error Pic:
[image: Error Pic]

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing something that checks if it's just a  normal word and if so then don't do the `http://`, for example ive got a txt document with A LOT of English words that you can use to check if its a normal word, like so:

```
if (re.findall(r'\b'+ re.escape(word1) + r'\b', contents, re.MULTILINE))
```

assign word1 to your word and contents to the dictionary

here is another example:

```
import re
with open('dictionary.txt') as fh:
    contents = fh.read()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to check if its a link? Like search if it ends with 'org', 'com', etc...

Comment: maybe, but this is the way I would do it

Comment: Thanks anyways. I'll try it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If that helped, read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). - @Hunter

Comment: One more thing, could you explain setScheme method for me?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I assume the ``setScheme`` adds the ``HTTP`` to the search bar, please don't rely on this because I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the url to the search engine search explicitly if the query does or doesn't match some criteria

At its most basic, you could use `urllib.parse.urlparse` for this, though it may not be an exact fit for all addresses, as it expects a scheme prefix, which most people don't bother with and let the `http(s)` be implicitly added by the browser

```py
>>> import urllib.parse
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("https://example.com")   # full example
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='example.com', path='', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("cats")                  # search works
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='cats', params='', query='', fragment='')
>>> urllib.parse.urlparse("example.com")           # fails for missing scheme
ParseResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='example.com', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

A quick test for an intended URL without a `scheme` to hint that an address is a `netloc` would be if the parsed `path` contains `.`

Alternatively, you could add some character (perhaps a space   or keyword like `d` or `s` before searches)

You may also need to URL encode your string (exchanging   for `+`, `?` for `%3F`, etc.), which can also be done by `urllib.parse`'s [`urllib.parse.quote_plus`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote_plus)

```py
>>> urllib.parse.quote_plus("What does a url-encoded cat query look like?")
'What+does+a+url-encoded+cat+query+look+like%3F'
```

[Duck Duck Go Search Parameters](https://duckduckgo.com/params)

All together

```py
import urllib.parse

url_search_template = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={}"
keyword_search = "d "

text = self.urlbar.text()

def probably_a_search(s):
    # check for prefix first to prevent matches against a search like 3.1415
    if s.startswith(keyword_search):
        return True, s[len(keyword_search):]  # slice search prefix
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(s)
    if parsed_url.scheme or parsed_url.netloc:
        return False, s
    if "." in parsed_url.path:
        return False, s
    return True, s

is_search, text = probably_a_search(text)
if is_search:
    text = url_search_template.format(urllib.parse.quote_plus(text.strip()))
q = QUrl(text)
```

To get a more accurate test against the TLD (rather than the simple presence of `.`), a 3rd-party library like https://pypi.org/project/tld/ may work better for you